# Is it useful to check if a Java collection is empty before beginning iteration?

Tags: java, collections, garbage-collection, iteration, micro-optimization

In the two styles below, an `Iterator` object is allocated.  Is it useful to check if the collection is empty before iterating?  I don't know if this qualifies as "premature optimization".  Hopefully, someone with deep knowledge of JVM garbage collectors can provide insight.

Also, I don't know how the Java compiler handles for-each loops.  I assume style **B** is converted to style **A** automatically.  But... maybe an empty check is included.

**Loop Style A**

```
Collection<String> collection = ...
Iterator<String> iter = collection.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String value = iter.next();
    // do stuff
    // maybe call iter.remove()
}
```

**Loop Style B**

```
Collection<String> collection = ...
for (String value : collection) {
    // do stuff
}
```

**Loop Style A (Modified)**

```
Collection<String> collection = ...
if (!collection.isEmpty()) {
    Iterator<String> iter = collection.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String value = iter.next();
        // do stuff
        // maybe call iter.remove()
    }
}
```

**Loop Style B (Modified)**

```
Collection<String> collection = ...
if (!collection.isEmpty()) {
    for (String value : collection) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: why check for empty, that is defensive programming at its worst!, checking for `null` is one thing, but checking for empty is just bad practice.

Comment: Why? I can see the benefit...instead of accessing the iterator and checking a method call to see if there is a `next`, which is what the JVM will be doing on a `for(Object obj : objects)`, it will just bypass all that code if the collection is empty...as far as I can see it's an optimization, now if it's a good one, that's another matter...

Comment: It seems all the existing answers missed the [tag:micro-optimization] tag and that this is a performance not correctness question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is pretty definitely going to be a *premature* optimization, if it can ever help.  Your loop would have to be extremely performance critical, and usually called with empty collections, *and* for some reason unable to optimize away most of the cost of creating an actual iterator object.

In that perfect storm, this massive source ugliness could possibly be justified.  But more likely you could rearrange something to help the compiler optimize better, like keeping your iterator local.

---

**The iterator object is (usually?) function-local and therefore cheap to create (could just live in registers, no heap allocation needed).**  See https://www.beyondjava.net/escape-analysis-java for some details about how JVMs do "scalar replacement" on an Object if escape analysis proves that it's purely local, no references to it are visible to other code.  So the possible savings don't even include a memory allocation.

If this did JIT-compile to a separate check before doing something, it's extra instructions that always run even when the collection is not empty.

**Optimize for the most common case.**  Instead of adding extra code to slightly speed up the rare empty case, leave it out to speed up the common non-empty case.

I think most loops tend to run on non-empty collections.  Small is common for some cases, but empty is usually rare.  Perhaps you have a loop that often or usually runs on empty collections, e.g. a rarely-used feature in a program.  Then it's worth thinking about optimizing for that case.  (Whether this is a useful way to go about it is another matter)

This extra call to `collection.isEmpty()` might just optimize into the loop condition anyway, if it JIT-compiles to a simple pointer-increment loop over an array, with a start and end pointer both kept in registers.  That's the best case, but then the extra source noise is useless and what you would have gotten anyway.

---

You could argue that if `for (String value : collection)` doesn't already compile to the most efficient way to loop over a collection, that's the compiler + JVM's fault, and you shouldn't have to make your source ugly for it.  That's probably true to a point, although introducing a call to `.isEmpty()` isn't something a compiler or runtime can do unless they can inline that method to see that it's really checking the same thing an iterator would.  But with JIT compilation, everything is available to be inlined.

---

**TL:DR: It's likely that a good JIT compiler doesn't really spend any real work creating an iterator for most simple collections, and there's nothing to be saved.**

In other cases, it's still probably better (for performance) not to do this unless your loop usually runs on empty collections, or (even more unlikely) iterator creation is somehow *very* expensive.

Answer (score 1):

No , you don't have to check for empty. The first iteration will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

iter.hasNext() method will return true/false value. if collection has no element in it then iterator simply returns false on executing statement iter.hasNext() and loop will be terminated gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to check if the collection is empty. If you are iterating using a for loop or using while loop with iterator, it will not get into the iteration if the collection is empty.

But when you are iterating the collection, you should check whether the collection is not null. It might throw `NullPointerException` if the collection is null and you try to iterate using loop or iterator.

You need not to check if the collection is empty.